# [actions-on-google]Can't talk to my test app in Simulator

Tags: actions-on-google

I always encounter this problem when doing the test, may I ask how to solve.

**My app's information**

[image: My app's information]

**not support**

[image: not support]

action.json

```
 {
  "actions": [{
    "name": "actions.devices",
    "deviceControl": {
    },
    "fulfillment": {
      "conversationName": "automation"
    }
  }],
  "conversations": {
    "automation" :
    {
      "name": "automation",
      "url": "https://xxxxxxxxxxx"
    }
  }
}
```

In google home app, I can find this app[Vine control], which can successfully send action.devices.SYNC through account linking and get the device, but I can not "talk to my test app" or "talk to Vine control".

**Home Control**

[image: Home Control]

**add**

[image: add]

**talk**

[image: talk]

Answer (score 2):

Smart Home apps are not conversational. You do not "talk to Vine Control". After linking your account and syncing devices, you control them directly.

"Set home to cool" or "Set room to 75" are valid commands.

These will also work in the simulator.

Comment: Thank you very much,So it is,I see

Comment: If you have a different question, it is probably best to ask it as another question rather than piggy-back it onto one that Nick answered.

Comment: You can't edit it. Most of the time it makes sense, but it doesn't work for Smart Home projects.

Answer (score 0):

In Dialogflow, 
click on Integrations
then the first Google
On this page click Test (bottom right)
wait
Then when the box appears click View in Console (above Test button)
Now say Test my ... app name